# Positioning an element within bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a gallery kind of display. What I'm trying to achieve is to put titles for those items within their display box.

Check jsfiddle for the scenario:
https://jsfiddle.net/xry7ezb9/5/

The problem is that the parent element uses bootstrap `col` class which creates padding on both sides of the element (which is, of course, considered part of the element size) and thus a child element takes that as the 100% width to adapt.

The result I'm trying to achieve is the second gallery item. But the way it is achieved is... "Hacky" (apologies for terminology) since i define the values in a hard-coded way and relying on the fact that Bootstrap does not change that. Also, I'm certain there is another way to achieve this.

The last `div` element has the correct width by itself but since i can't use absolute positioning to put it into correct place, I'm not sure, how i can apply this.

Also, not sure if 3rd tile approach is really viable (though it might be due to the fact, that gallery item height is hard-coded).

How should I approach this while keeping responsiveness in mind?

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.gallery-item-container {
 height: 200px;
 max-height: 200px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-item-logo {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100%;
 border: unset;
 border-radius: unset;
 background: unset;
 border: solid 1px #929292;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.gallery-item-logo:hover{
    background-color:#c7c7c7;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.gallery-item-logo > img {
    max-height: 70%;
    max-width: 90%;
}

.speaker-name, .item-title {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.no-absolute {
    /* position: absolute; */
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.no-absolute-top-margin-test{
    height: 15%;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

/* Offsetting bootstrap col class padding on the parent (it expands parent body by 15px on each side thus children inherit that extra width) */
.col-padding-offset {
    max-width: calc(100% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    max-height: 15%; // Separate this
    height: 15%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">

    <div class="gallery-item-container mb-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        <div class="gallery-item-logo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#participant_modal_8">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/lotr/images/8/8d/Gandalf-2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130209172436">
            <span class="icon-focus"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="item-title">
            <p><b>test title</b></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item-container mb-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        <div class="gallery-item-logo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#participant_modal_16">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/lotr/images/8/8d/Gandalf-2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130209172436">
            <span class="icon-focus"></span>

        </div>

        <div class="item-title col-padding-offset">
            <p><b>test title</b></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item-container mb-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        <div class="gallery-item-logo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#participant_modal_11">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/lotr/images/8/8d/Gandalf-2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130209172436">
            <span class="icon-focus"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="no-absolute no-absolute-top-margin-test">
            <p><b>test title</b></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item-container mb-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        <div class="gallery-item-logo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#participant_modal_2">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/lotr/images/8/8d/Gandalf-2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130209172436">
            <span class="icon-focus"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="no-absolute">
            <p><b>test title</b></p>
        </div>

    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The padding is always `15px`, so you can could do this:

```
.speaker-name, .item-title {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

[Your fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8kmds093/)

Comment: It's `15px` to both left and right, for a total of `30px`. I did that in `col-padding-offset` class (2nd tile/item). Just was not sure if that's the right way to go

Comment: And *just* setting width with an offset is not the answer, because `left: 0` sets element at the parent padding left. Need an offset for that too (also done in `col-padding-offset`)

Comment: @NulisDefo Yes you can do that if the padding does not change.

Comment: Change left to 15px and make the width calc(100% - 30px) and you're there ;)

Comment: @NulisDefo I updated the fiddle and code. Have a look. Works great

Comment: So the `col-padding-offset` class approach then. Gotcha